# java null pointer exception Android studio

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying something. I'm want to create new object and add in list. But I get NullPointerException. My code is

```
private List<HisseModel> hisseListe=null;`
HisseModel model = new HisseModel();
        model.setSymbol("abv");
        model.setChange("123");
        model.setCurrency("234");

        HisseModel model2 = new HisseModel();
        model2.setSymbol("abv2");
        model2.setChange("1232");
        model2.setCurrency("2342");

        hisseListe.add(model);
        hisseListe.add(model2);`
```

Why it's not working ?

Comment: Because you never initialized `hisseListe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here which is assigned to null

```
private List<HisseModel> hisseListe=null;
```

You need to initialize it like below

```
private List<HisseModel> hisseListe=new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is at below line

```
 private List<HisseModel> hisseListe=null;
```

`null` is not an object, so you can't access it - that's a NullPointerException.

You'll need to **initialize a list** (like below) and then add object into it.

```
private List<HisseModel> hisseListe = new ArrayList <HisseModel>();
```